# Fix VBA code that converts empty cells into dates

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on some VB projects that has to do with generation of new excel sheets and some data analysis. In the final sheet generated, there are some columns that contain excel default dates (00.01.1900)

I later figured out there is a section of the code that converts blank cells from a previous sheet into the default dates in the final sheet. Here is some portion of the code I figured is the problem

```
Set rng_col = ws.Cells.Find(What:="Total Discrepancies", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlHeaderRow, SearchOrder:=xlHeaderRow, SearchFormat:=False) 'Total Discrepancies
    If Not (rng_col Is Nothing) Then
        col_total = rng_col.Column
        len_d = ws.Cells(1, len_col_max).End(xlToLeft).Column
        len_l = ws.Cells(len_lines_max, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        For cpt = 2 To len_l
            For k = col_total + 1 To len_d
                ws.Cells(cpt, col_total).Value = CInt(ws.Cells(cpt, col_total).Value) + CInt(ws.Cells(cpt, k).Value)
            Next k
            If ws.Cells(cpt, col_total).Value = 0 Then
                ws.Cells(cpt, col_total).Value = ""
            End If

            If col_first <> 0 And col_last <> 0 Then
                ws.Cells(cpt, col_first).Value = CDate(ws.Cells(cpt, col_first).Value)
                ws.Cells(cpt, col_last).Value = CDate(ws.Cells(cpt, col_last).Value)
            End If
        Next cpt
```

So what can I can change (I'm guessing its from the last 4 lines) from this code that would leave the empty cells in the prvs sheet to remain the same in the final sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add this IF...Then on the last 2 rows:

```
if ws.Cells(cpt, col_first).value <> 0 then ws.Cells(cpt, col_first).Value = CDate(ws.Cells(cpt, col_first).Value)
if ws.Cells(cpt, col_last).value <> 0 then ws.Cells(cpt, col_last).Value = CDate(ws.Cells(cpt, col_last).Value)
```

Keep in mind that VBA is not converting dates, it's just 00.01.1900 is equal to 0 (zero), so your zeros are formated as dates.